# Azure Service Bus Topic trigger in Function App- limiting the number of message read

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a service bus trigger in an Azure function app which reads the messages ( which are in Json format) coming from the subscription. I would like to know if there is a way to limit the number of request processed by Service bus. So for example if my service bus get triggered and it has 20 messages to be processed, I would like only the first 10 to be processed and then next 10. How can I achieve that?

I am asking this because I am doing some manipulation with the received messages, first i creating a list of the information and running some sql query over it in C# and would prefer my code to NOT handle all the messages at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can configure this in the *host.json*. Here's the documentation:
[learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=csharp#hostjson-settings)

Just add this `"maxConcurrentCalls": 10` to the *messageHandlerOptions*, then it will just process 10 messages simultaneously.